# How can I exclude anchor tags from jQuery UI Selectable?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm making a calendar with jQuery selectable, so you can select the li items and add events to the dates selected.

Within each li is an anchor tag that I want to add a javascript onclick function to it - but the jQuery UI selectable function seems to be conflicting.

How do I exclude item's that the jQuery UI selectable function is applied to? I am trying to use the 'NOT' selector but it's not working...

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
            <ol id='selectable' class='selectable'>
                <li class='ui-widget-content' data-date='' date-uid=''>
                    <span class='dayOfWeek disabled'>1</span>
                    <span class='dayName disabled'>Thursday</span>
                    <a href='#' data-travel-day-id='' class='close' onclick='alert("hi");return false;'></a>
                </li>
            </ol>

           $(function () {
            $("#selectable").selectable();
           });
```

So I'm just trying to get my 'hi' message to popup and for it to not select that list item when they click the anchor tag.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
  cancel: "a.close"   
});
```

jQuery UI selectable option: [Cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-cancel)

Comment: You sir, are a god damn hero.